# Access Denied when trying to edit page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access-denied, wiki-pages

all users (including farm admin) are having an issue editing existing pages on all sites on a give web app (another web app on the same server is fine.

Whenever a user goes to edit a page, they get a 403 error (https://ibin.co/2zalK70FhiPC.png). I've loked at ULS, Event Viewer, and ProcMon.

I've done some research. Several sites mention to make sure authenticated users have access to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Web80.Contoso.com80\bin`, but that doesn't seem to affect the issue.

ULS says:

```
 SPRequest.OpenWeb: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://buildeagle.com/
```

and then

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb()         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_SecurableObjectImpl()         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.get_HasUniqueRoleAssignments()        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAccessRequestsUtility.TryGetAccessRequestListCore(SPWeb web, SPList& arl, Boolean ignoreRoleAssignments, Boolean& incompatibleListWithSameNameExists)         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAccessRequestsUtility.TryGetAccessRequestList(SPWeb web, SPList& arl, Boolean ignoreRoleAssignments)      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.InitControls(SPWeb webAsSystem, SPList listAsSystem, SPListItem itemAsSystem, SPObjectType requestType)        at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OnLoad>b__0()      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()         at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)      at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AccessRequestsDialog.OnLoad(EventArgs e)        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()        at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)         at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)      at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)        at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)      at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)        at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)      at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)        at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)        at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)        at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Windows event viewer is complaining about the Managed metadata service not running, but I don't think that's related, since the other web application isn't crashing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check farm/service accounts are not locked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the IIS Web Application wasn't using the farm account, and didn't have enough permissions.

Comment: You shouldnt run your IIS App Pools as the Farm admin, but you are right that it was likely a permission issue.  Your app pool account needs to be in the IIS_IUSRS group to have access to the temp directory that IIS uses  in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files. You should also make sure the IIS Authorization setting match your preferred auth method

Comment: FYI: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx - account permissions & security settings for SharePoint Server 2013

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look in below things,

1. If Master page or the Page Layout used by pages is checked out then user may get access denied error so **make sure that master page or page layout is Checked in & Published.**
2. Check If User having permission (Read/Edit) over Master Page Gallery. If doesn't then give **Read or edit access to users on Master Page Gallery.**

Comment: There were some page layouts and master pages checked out. I checked those back in, but still have the same error.

Comment: You published it ?

Comment: I don't see how to publish master pages from either Sharepoint Designer or Sharepoint itself.